# UIImage assignment not happening in swift when update image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

The image in my app doesn't update when I assign the new image to it.

```
func updateUI () {
    nameField.text = founders[founderIndex].name

    print("founders[founderindex].image",founders[founderIndex].image)
    print("picture.image",picture.image!)
    print(picture)
    picture.image = founders[founderIndex].image
    print("founders[founderindex].image   ",founders[founderIndex].image)
    print("picture.image",picture.image!)
}
```

The output for this looks like:

```
founders[founderindex].image    <UIImage: 0x17409b710> size {1200, 1200} orientation 0 scale 1.000000

picture.image     <UIImage: 0x17409b490> size {1200, 1200} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
<UIImageView: 0x100f14d20; frame = (125 3; 124 124); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x174038da0>>

founders[founderindex].image    <UIImage: 0x17409b710> size {1200, 1200} orientation 0 scale 1.000000

picture.image     <UIImage: 0x17409b490> size {1200, 1200} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
```

The `founders[founderIndex].image` doesn't get assigned to the `picture.image` ever. I've looked around, but haven't been able to get it to change from the image it is initialized with.

Comment: `print (founders[founderIndex].image)`, whats the output?

Comment: Please do not post an image of your code. Please replace the image with the actual code copy and pasted as text.

Comment: @Mr.UB It's the first line in the log output shown in the question.

Comment: print (picture), whats the output?

Comment: the output to print(picture) is <UIImageView: 0x149d3b7a0; frame = (125 3; 124 124); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1702216a0>>

Comment: the output to print(founders[founderIndex].image) is <UIImage: 0x170091800> size {1200, 1200} orientation 0 scale 1.000000

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the problem was with the initializer. When I had an image in the initializer it would cache that and only use that. I'm not entirely sure why. I ended up saving the actual asset names in variable and initializing the imageName (as a string and not a UIImage) and using that to load the image with:

```
picture.image = UIImage(named:founders[founderIndex].imageName)
```

If I initialize anything but the empty string it will do the same thing as before and keep the default/initialized value only. So I guess the key is not assigning any default value in the initializer.